# Can we deploy react UI application on the weblogic server?

Tags: reactjs, weblogic

I need to deploy react UI application  along with my backend rest APIs on weblogic server.
How do I achieve this scenario?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can package your react app in a jar file and put all the static resources (index.html, javascript, css, etc) under the META-INF/resources/frontend folder of that jar file.  You can then add that jar file as a dependency of the war file that contains your backend rest apis.  Then when you enter <context_path>/frontend/index.html in a browser, it should serve your reactjs app.